# How to resolve dependency com.github.afollestad:inquiry:b13a58b902 not found error in AIDE?

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aide-ide

I am working on building an icon pack using material IOS  template  repository from github in AIDE. You can find the repository at https://github.com/materialos/Android-Icon-Pack   . But I am getting an error , —dependency com.github.afollestad:inquiry:b13a58b902 not found error in build.gradle file. And the IDE is also not recognizing library resources and giving errors ,like unknown entity R. Please help me to resolve the problem This is the build.gradle file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent, "MaterialOS-${variant.versionName}.apk")
        }
}

    // Note to self, sample uses same keystore as Cabinet

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
}

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.materialos.icons"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "2.0.1"
        generatedDensities = []
    }

   buildTypes {
 //        debug {
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.production
//        }
        release {
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.production
            // Disable Proguard so our drawable-nodpi resources aren't removed
           minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}

repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':licensing')

    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('com.github.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.3.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

compile 'com.github.afollestad:bridge:3.2.0'
compile 'com.github.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.1'
compile 'com.github.afollestad:assent:0.2.1'
compile 'com.github.afollestad:inquiry:b13a58b902'
compile 'com.github.afollestad:icon-request:1.3.1'

compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.5'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.2.1'

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:1.0.6@aar'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.apps.muzei:muzei-api:2.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'

compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
compile 'com.pluscubed:insets-dispatcher:0.1.3'
```

}

Comment: post your build.gradle files

Comment: I have added the build.gradle file as per your request .I have also specified the url of the repository in the question.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  i have specified what you asked , please give any answer or comment

Answer (score 0):

1) delete or rename old project folder

2) clone the project again (https://github.com/materialos/Android-Icon-Pack)

3) navigate to app folder, open 'build.gradle', click 'yes', wait for maven repository download to complete

4) replace

```
dependencies {
compile project(path: ':licensing')

compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.2.2'
compile 'com.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.3.6'
compile 'com.afollestad:bridge:3.2.5'
compile 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.3'
compile 'com.afollestad:assent:0.2.5'
compile 'com.afollestad:icon-request:1.5.2'
compile 'com.afollestad:inquiry:4.1.2'

compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$GOOGLE_LIBS"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$GOOGLE_LIBS"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$GOOGLE_LIBS"
compile "com.android.support:design:$GOOGLE_LIBS"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$GOOGLE_LIBS"
compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$GOOGLE_LIBS"

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:1.0.6@aar'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'

compile 'com.google.android.apps.muzei:muzei-api:2.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'

compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.32'
compile 'com.pluscubed:insets-dispatcher:0.1.3'

compile 'org.bitbucket.frankmonza:kustomapi:1.1'
}
```

with fixed version

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
compile project(':licensing')

compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.2.2'
compile 'com.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.3.6'
compile 'com.afollestad:bridge:3.2.5'
compile 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.3'
compile 'com.afollestad:assent:0.2.5'
compile 'com.afollestad:icon-request:1.5.2'
compile 'com.afollestad:inquiry:4.1.2'

compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'


compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:1.0.6@aar'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'

compile 'com.google.android.apps.muzei:muzei-api:2.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'

compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.32'
compile 'com.pluscubed:insets-dispatcher:0.1.3'

compile 'org.bitbucket.frankmonza:kustomapi:1.1'
}
```

I had to reimport the support libs and fix 1 typo. Refresh Build and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for help , i will surely try  your suggestion . But by the way please do specify if you were successful in building an app apk with those resources on AIDE , android app ,yes  specifically AIDE  .  Even though i will try it in both desktop and android i still wanted to know  .